# How to parse どうかなさいましたか and what does it mean in English?

Tags: grammar

I am interested to decompose どうかなさいましたか into its atomic words. My attempt is as follows, is it correct?

- どうか
- なさいました
- か

I don't know the dictionary form of  なさいました. I totally get confused.
How to parse どうかなさいましたか and what does it mean in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

なさいました is the past tense form of なさいます, なさいます is the polite form of なさる, and なさる is an honorific form of する, "do", so なさいました means しました. どうかなさいましたか is the honorific way of saying どうかしましたか？ "What happened?" "What's the matter?"

Comment: なさいます is the polite form of なさる rather than なさう?

Comment: なさう・・・？ I don't think we have a verb なさう...　なさいました was etymologically なさりました, and　イ音便 occurred (I think)

Comment: すう becomes すいます, 買う becomes かいます. So it should follow the same pattern I think.

Comment: Yeah, but およぐ becomes およいだ, not およぎた, right? It's イ音便.

Comment: Every gu becomes ida, such as sawagu->sawaida, oyogu->oyoida, etc. They keep the rule obeyed.

Comment: Does [this page](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%94%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) help? "「なさる」「くださる」「おっしゃる」「いらっしゃる」の連用形に助動詞「ます」が続くときはイ音便化して「なさい（ます）」「ください（ます）」「おっしゃい（ます）」「いらっしゃい（ます）」となることが多い。" (When the auxiliary ます follows なさる, くださる, おっしゃる, いらっしゃる, they often change to なさい(ます), ください(ます), おっしゃい(ます), いらっしゃい(ます).)

Comment: If we had a verb なさう, it would certainly transformed to "なさいます". Gu becomes ida because of the イ音便, so when you say "every gu becomes ida", you are talking two rules composed: sawagu -> sawagita -> sawaida, the same passage as なさる →なさりました→なさいました.

Comment: @FriendlyGhost You could also include ござる in that list, too (people say ございます rather than ござります).  I think the reason it isn't listed on that website is because ござる is archaic, so ございます is considered a separate word now.  But if you look at it historically, it belongs with the other four honorific verbs.